# Fspy issues in Blender

Tags: camera, fspy

I'm trying to setup my camera so I can start modelling this image...
[image]

So I setup my Fspy shot like so...
[image]

But when I start modelling the basic shapes they look positioned right in the camera viewport but are way off in reality. Am I missing something?
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your x axis estimations, especially the bottom one, seem off.  Is that it?

Comment: @DaleCieslak I find it depends a lot on assumptions about what is or isn't an edge.  The left most Y axis in the fspy above is suspect because I don't know that those three abutments are aligned.  I try to stick to only continuous straight edges.  Also, holding the shift key while moving the points is critical.  I also turn 'dim image' off, but that's a matter of taste.  Sometimes I find using the box guide helps.  But mostly it's practice, practice, practice.

Answer (score 1):

Problems you will always have when working with photographs in fSpy are:

- the photos might have lens distortion
- things are not always perfectly straight in real life
- you draw the lines not according to the real-world properties

For the last point here is something that @MartyFouts already suspected, maybe the building parts are not aligned the way you've drawn the lines. For the two green *Y* lines labeled 2 in your fSpy screenshot, here are images from different perspectives:

[image: fSpy lines]

Answer (score 1):

In the end I went with this solution from Marko Matosevic on the Sydney Blender FB page...

"Because you need to start with one face and extrude from there. If you are adding a secondary cube, you don’t know where that cube is in relation to the other cube."

Major brain fart from me, thanks Marko!

Comment: Yes, extruding from the first cube of course puts the second one on top of it. The real building has the cubes overlapping, but I guess that's not to hard to achieve after extruding.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that your image has two vanishing points, not three. You have to properly set the principal point in such a case. In your particular case it should be lower to get the proper alignment for Z. As in the attached image (the orange dot, roughly placed on the car).

[image]

This is a common mistake people make using fSpy. Yesterday I released a complete tutorial on how to use fSpy (covering all its options). It presents how to deal with images having different number of vanishing points.

I hope it helps:
https://youtu.be/daiMOYR8GS8